# Java: Printing array in one command

Tags: java, arrays

How can I print an array, `array1`, in one command like `array.toString` or something similar that actually  prints `array1` as an array like `1 3 4` or something similar and not as a string like `[I@1242719c`. Maybe we can turn it to a `ArrayList` and then we can print it easily?

Comment: @lngo:Is this a math ex? I tried 'array.toString' and prints it with a loop. It's whether you recall the static method of Arrays or not, no?

Comment: no it's not a math ex. It's a question of politeness if one expects help to give as detailed information as possible. Please remember that people answering here do that voluntary, it's not that they are paid by stackoverflow and it's there duty.

Comment: Sure, but i did explain what I think or suggested the ArrayList.
I don't know what you more expected. Writing in the question: "How can I print an array in one command?" would be rude indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Arrays.toString(array1)
```

and if it is multidimensional array

```
Arrays.deepToString(array1)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Arrays.toString(array1)
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

```
 Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

According to the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), it calls the `toString()` method of the objects in your array.